# React Native Firebase TypeError when importing

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am developing an Android and IOS mobile app using React Native. I want to use Firebase for my database but when I install `npm install --save firebase` and then I `import firebase from 'firebase'`.

I would get this error saying

> "TypeError: undefined is not a function(evaluating '_iteratortypeof
>   Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator: "@@iterator"')"

This is the screenshot of my output

[image]

I want to create a login screen for my app with a database. Any other suggestion can help if using Firebase for my mobile app.

This is my coding if it helps.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
Platform,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';


export default class Login extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
state = {
    email: "Enter email",
 password: "Enter password"
};





render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Create an account below</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ email: text })}
                    value={this.state.email}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity

                >
                    <View>
                        <Text>Log In Existing</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity

                >
                    <View>
                        <Text>Create New User</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Comment: Outra here the content oficial your file that have the import...

Answer (score 0):

which babel version is used for compilation? all the babel plugin and preset should match of babel version.
Please check the babel version and presets.

Comment: How do I check the babel plugin and preset version?

Comment: please check in package.json file

Comment: Im using this "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"

Comment: you have to require core-js. you can find the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902#issuecomment-373964965)